# What is the equivalent method of Word.Body.getOoxml() in c# open xml sdk?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, office-js

I need to read the contents of the header in a word document using c# and save it somewhere and later insert it to another word document using javascript wordapi.
I know that in "officejs wordapi" we can use insertOoxml method to insert into header for example:   `getHeader("Primary").insertOoxml(ooxmlStringFetchedFromServer, Word.InsertLocation.replace);`

But how can i get this ooxml using c#?
Also i already tried `OuterXml` property of `Header` object but apparently its not an ooxml.

**Update**:
I figure out with this code we can get the right format to be used in javascript wordapi:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument word = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\sample.docx", false))
{
    var ooxmlStringFetchedFromServer = word.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.FirstOrDefault().OpenXmlPackage.ToFlatOpcString();
}
```

So the correct format is "FlatOpc".
Now i can use the following javascript code to add this FlatOpc to the Word document:

```
async function run() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        context.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("Primary").insertOoxml(ooxmlStringFetchedFromServer, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

But now i have another problem, which is the following code does not returning the FlatOpc of the Header section, instead it returns only the FlatOpc of the body section!

```
word.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.FirstOrDefault().OpenXmlPackage.ToFlatOpcString();
```

Comment: HOW would you be reading the header in C#? It's not clear from your question or from the tags you use. Maybe show us the code?